# Subset with measure as small as we like

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E \subset R^n$ be Lebesgue measurable with $0 < |E|< \infty$ and let $\alpha > 0$, can we prove $\exists A \subset E$ s.t.
$$0 < |E \ \backslash A| < \alpha$$

This seems to be natural. But don't know how to prove it. Thank you.

Comment: You could just let A be E minus a point in E and then you are just left with a point which has lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: You need to state the question much more carefully. The answer to the question as stated is obviously no if $|E|=\infty$. And if $|E|<\infty$ then $A=E$ works for the question as stated...

Comment: Sorry, I edited it...

Comment: Also you need $|E| > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_r(p)$ denote the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $p$.
Show (using compactness of $[-N,N]^n$) that there is a point $p \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $|E \cap B_r(p)| > 0 $ for all $r > 0$.  Take $A = E \backslash B_r(p)$ for $p$ sufficiently small...